# Movie with robotic child, robots fighting, underwater city with a ferris wheel

Tags: story-identification, robots

When I was younger, only about 10 or so, there was a movie that my parents were watching. I can not for the life of me find out what it is called, but it sort of goes like this:

A young boy and his mother (both Caucasian) were talking about something in his room. The room had a window shaped as a circle, with nothing in the background. It was late at night, the child woke up, and I think he was trying to find his mother but on the way he was taken (maybe kidnapped) somewhere with bright flood lights and robots fighting each other. The boy didn't know why he was there, but discovered that he was a robot and that he had to fight or something. It was set in a forest in a cage as well.

In a different scene you have him in a vehicle going underwater, into what may have been a sunken city; there were buildings and a rusted ferris wheel. The boy enters a huge building that has a man at the top of it.

I loved this movie; it made me cry and actually feel something.

Comment: How long ago were you ten? Was it animated or live-action? Anything you can remember, even the smallest detail, might help

Answer (score 48):

All of the plot elements which you cited are in the 2001 movie ["AI" directed by Steven Spielberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.I._Artificial_Intelligence).  Just do a Google Images search on "Artificial Intelligence movie" or "AI movie" and you will get a lot of screen captures from the movie that may trigger your memories.  Although your 10 year old self forgot aspects of the overall story line, the movie has the following elements that match your memory:

Set in the near future:

- a "boy" that is a robot that is designed to mimic a real boy for parents that have lost a child (his owner's son has a fatal illness and is placed into suspended animation)
- the "boy" is told the story of [Pinocchio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Pinocchio) by his mother/owner in a bedroom at night with a round window, and the "boy" starts to obsess over the course of the movie to become a real boy
- the "boy" is taken away and abandoned into a forest by his parents/owners when their real son recovers from the near fatal illness and is hostile toward his "new brother"
- the "boy" is captured in the forest and taken to "Flesh Fair" where captured robots are first caged together, and then must fight each other in a flood-lit arena
- in the movie's near-future setting, global warming has flooded New York City.

  - the "boy" is taken to the top of a bottom-flooded skyscraper where he meets a man which is his creator, and a copy of himself
  - The "boy" is taken underwater in a vehicle to a sunken "Coney Island" amusement park which indeed had a submerged Ferris wheel (and is a crucial plot element)

Set in the far future:

- at the end of the movie, the "boy" is recovered after 2000 years frozen in the waters in submerged New York, and placed into a room with a round window (that recreated his former home 2000 years ago), and there are scenes with a facsimile of his former human mother/owner.  Some of these scenes parallel the beginning of the movie.

Comment: This was my first thought as well, good summary.

Comment: To the last point about the Blue Fairy - he does meet a man at the top of a building, but this is before the Blue Fairy scene.